# Quickest way to crop/clip a complex SpatialPolygonsDataFrame using another polygon

Tags: r, performance, gis, spatial, r-raster

What is the quickest way of cropping (clipping) a complex SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with the `@data` preserved in R using another, possibly complex, SpatialPolygon? I know of two ways (shown under). The `raster` way is quicker for less complex SpatialPolygonsDataFrames and returns a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame as in the example. It gets slow with large SpatialPolygonsDataFrames, though. The `rgeos` way is quicker for large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, but [it sometimes fails with very complex geometries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048527/1082004) and does not return SpatialPolygonsDataFrames as default.

I have not paid attention to the GIS development in R lately and there might well be quicker ways of doing this by now.

The example polygons are small to honor people's computers and bandwidth. Consider the "real" polygons 50-1000 MB.

Setup:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)

dt <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries()
clip_boundary <- sp::SpatialPolygons(list(sp::Polygons(
list(sp::Polygon(data.frame(lon = c(0, 180, 180, 0), lat = c(40, 40, 80, 80)))), ID = 1)))
```

The `rgeos` way:

```
system.time({
clipped.dt <- rgeos::gIntersection(dt, clip_boundary, byid = TRUE)
ids <- sapply(slot(clipped.dt, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"))
ids <- sapply(strsplit(ids, " "), "[", 1) 

tmp.df <- data.frame(dt@data[ids,])
names(tmp.df) <- names(dt@data)

out <- sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(clipped.dt, tmp.df, match.ID = FALSE)
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.069   0.002   0.074 

class(out)
# [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "sp"
```

The `raster` way:

```
system.time({
  out <- raster::crop(dt, clip_boundary)
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.042   0.001   0.043 

class(out)
# [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "sp"
```

A plot for a reference (not relevant for the question):

```
plot(out)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Much of R's geospatial work can now be done using the `sf` package.

https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/index.html

It looks like it might be a touch faster than raster and sp.

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sp)
#library(raster)
#library(rgeos)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.7.2, GDAL 2.4.2, PROJ 5.2.0
library(ggplot2)

# Original data 
dt <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries()
clip_boundary <- sp::SpatialPolygons(list(sp::Polygons(
  list(sp::Polygon(data.frame(lon = c(0, 180, 180, 0), lat = c(40, 40, 80, 80)))), ID = 1)))

# Original data as sf objects
dt_sf <- st_as_sf(dt)
boundary_sf <- st_as_sf(clip_boundary)

# clip 
clipped <- st_crop(dt_sf, boundary_sf)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries

#plot
ggplot(clipped) + geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
system.time({
  out <- st_crop(dt_sf, boundary_sf)
})
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.019   0.000   0.018

system.time({
  out <- raster::crop(dt, clip_boundary)
})
#> Warning in raster::crop(dt, clip_boundary): non identical CRS
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.526   0.000   0.525

system.time({
  clipped.dt <- rgeos::gIntersection(dt, clip_boundary, byid = TRUE)
  ids <- sapply(slot(clipped.dt, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"))
  ids <- sapply(strsplit(ids, " "), "[", 1) 

  tmp.df <- data.frame(dt@data[ids,])
  names(tmp.df) <- names(dt@data)

  out <- sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(clipped.dt, tmp.df, match.ID = FALSE)
})
#> Warning in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td,
#> unaryUnion_if_byid_false, : spgeom1 and spgeom2 have different proj4 strings
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.045   0.000   0.045
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `sf` package. I had not thought of it. In the application I use the cropping, the shapes must be returned in `sp` format. The conversions make the `sf` solution slightly slower than the `rgeos` one (system times for one dataset I have: `rgeos` ~ 7 sec, `sf` ~ 9 sec and `raster` > 80 sec). However, your suggestion might well be the quickest so far if one already operates using `sf` objects. I will leave the question open for a while before accepting your answer. Maybe someone comes up with a faster solution we have not thought of.

Comment: The `sp` -> `sf` -> `sp` will slow things down.  I didn't realize `sp` was a requirement in your case.  R usually isn't very fast, but you can always throw a bigger computer at it.  I've found the `sf` way of doing spatial operations really is much more intuitive than `sp`.  Good luck.